# Django make field optional that gets check by integrity

Tags: django, forms, field

i want to make a field at my sign-up page optional so that the content of that field only gets checked if the user has provided these information, if not, simply skip the check for the data integrity:

> pubpgp = PGPKey.from_blob(request.POST['pubpgp'].rstrip("\r\n"))[0]

of the field pub pgp. But i don't know how to accomplishes this, any help is welcome.

models.py

```
pubpgp = models.TextField(verbose_name='Public RSA PGP Key - (ASCII-Armored)', blank=True, default='', max_length=3000)
```

views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pubpgp = PGPKey.from_blob(request.POST['pubpgp'].rstrip("\r\n"))[0]
            if pubpgp.key_algorithm == PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncryptOrSign:
                form.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Thanks for you Registration, you are now able to login.")
                return redirect(reverse('login'))
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Only RSA based PGP keys are allowed.")
        else:
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'signup.html', args)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: So are you saying that if the parameter `pubpgp` is _not_ supplied, then redirect straight to the `login` view?

Comment: Yes! exactly, thanks for reading

Comment: One thing I noticed is that, after executing the else of `if pubpgp.key_algorithm == PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncryptOrSign:`, no return statement can render that messages. Now to your question, the code looks quite right. Could you please elaborate more about `how to accomplishes this`? What is the error you got? If it is about pubpgp is required, you can try adding `null=True` to `pubpgp = models.TextField(verbose_name='Public RSA PGP Key - (ASCII-Armored)', blank=True, default='', max_length=3000)`. I think `null` and `blank` usually go hand in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to redirect to the `login` view if the `pubpgp` parameter is not supplied, or if it is supplied and indicates the correct algorithm, then this should just involve a small tweak to the conditional statement:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pubpgp = request.POST.get('pubpgp')
            # Allow redirect if pubpgp is empty or not empty but correct algorithm
            if not pubpgp or PGPKey.from_blob(pubpgp.rstrip("\r\n"))[0].key_algorithm == PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncryptOrSign:
                form.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Thanks for you Registration, you are now able to login.")
                return redirect(reverse('login'))
            else:
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Only RSA based PGP keys are allowed.")
        else:
            return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'signup.html', args)
```

Comment: Merci :D
Finally solved. I was about to get mad on this detail.